# Calling python function fetching 'c' like struct using cython and ctypes interface in c program

Tags: cython, ctypes

I am new to cython/ctypes, and i m trying to call python function from c program using cython interface, but the data is either empty or not correct. Here is the sample program

python function

```
$ cat c_struct.py
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7

from ctypes import *

class Request(Structure):
    _pack_ = 1
    _fields_ = [
            ('type', c_ubyte),
            ('subtype', c_ubyte),
            ('action', c_ubyte),
            ('checksum', c_ushort)
            ]

    def __repr__(self):
        return "'type': {}, 'subtype': {}, 'action': {}, 'checksum': {}".format(self.type,
                self.subtype, self.action, self.checksum)


req_msg = Request()
def get_message(typ):
    if typ == 1:
        req_msg.type = 12
        req_msg.subtype = 2
        req_msg.action = 3
        req_msg.checksum = 0x1234
        return req_msg
    else:
        return "String object From Python"
```

cython wrapper

```
$ cat caller.pyx
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '')

from c_struct import get_message

cdef public const void* get_data_frm_python(int typ):
    data = get_message(typ)
    print "Printing in Cython -",data
    return <const void*>data
```

and finally my 'C' caller

```
cat main.c
#include <Python.h>
#include "caller.h"
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    uint8_t type;
    uint8_t subtype;
    uint8_t action;
    uint16_t checksum;
} __attribute__ ((packed)) request_t;

int
main()
{
    PyImport_AppendInittab("caller", initcaller);
    Py_Initialize();
    PyImport_ImportModule("caller");

        const char* str = get_data_frm_python(2);
        printf("Printing in C - %s\n", str);

        const request_t* reqP = (request_t*)get_data_frm_python(1);
        printf("Printing in C - %u, %u, %u, %u\n", reqP->type, reqP->subtype, reqP->action, reqP->checksum);

    return 0;
}
```

and a simple makefile to build it

```
$ cat Makefile
target = main
cy_interface = caller

CY := cython
PYTHONINC := $(shell python-config --includes)
CFLAGS := -Wall $(PYTHONINC) -fPIC -O0 -ggdb3
LDFLAGS := $(shell python-config --ldflags)

CC=gcc

all: $(target)

%.c: %.pyx
        $(CY) $+

%.o: %.c
        $(CC) -fPIC $(CFLAGS) -c $+

$(target): $(cy_interface).o $(target).o
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS)
```

And finally the output :(

```
$ ./main
Printing in Cython - String object From Python
Printing in C -
Printing in Cython - 'type': 12, 'subtype': 2, 'action': 3, 'checksum': 4660
Printing in C - 1, 0, 0, 0
```

Can someone please help me in to understand on what am i doing wrong ?

Note :- If i change void* to char* atleast the string data is fetched properly, but segfaults for struct

```
$ cat caller.pyx
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '')

from c_struct import get_message

cdef public const void* get_data_frm_python(int typ):
    data = get_message(typ)
    print "Printing in Cython -",data
    return <const char*>data


$ ./main
Printing in Cython - String object From Python
Printing in C - String object From Python
Printing in Cython - 'type': 12, 'subtype': 2, 'action': 3, 'checksum': 4660
TypeError: expected string or Unicode object, Request found
Exception TypeError: 'expected string or Unicode object, Request found' in 'caller.get_data_frm_python' ignored
Segmentation fault
```

Comment: Request is not the struct itself, but the python object wrapping it. To get the address of the struct-object for c-code use ctypes.addressof

Comment: @ead - Could u please show an example ? did u mean `return ctypes.addressof(req_msg)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<const void*>data
```

`data` is a Python object (a `PyObject*`). This line casts that `PyObject*` to void. It definitely isn't reasonable to interpret a `PyObject*` as either a string or a `request*`.

```
<const char*>data
```

This gets a pointer to the first element of a Python string (which your struct isn't). The pointer is only valid while `data` is still alive. Unfortunately data is a function local variable so may be almost instantly freed. It's difficult to tell exactly what's going on here but it's definitely wrong.

---

I don't really understand what you're trying to achieve here so I'm struggling to give advice on how to do it better. Maybe drop ctypes and use Cython with a C union?

Comment: Thanks @DavidW for the response, isn't everything in python objects ? I don't have much internals of python, but when i `return req_msg` i m assuming it returns a reference/pointer ? so local variable (`data` ), would eventually return again ptr/ref.

Comment: Yes - essentially everything is Python objects. The point is that it once you've case Python objects to a `void*` you've lost all reference counting (so it's unlikely to be safe) and there isn't anything meaningful you can actually do with a `void*` Python object.

Comment: I realise this is an unhelpful answer because it only tells you that your code doesn't work. However, I really don't understand what you're trying to do, and I think it's likely to be hard to do safely.

Answer (score 0):

Anyways this did the trick for me, not a perfect one but something.

```
$ cat caller.pyx
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '')

from libc.stdint cimport uintptr_t
from c_struct import get_message

cdef public const void* get_data_frm_python(int typ):
    data = get_message(typ)
    if isinstance(data, str):
        return <const char*>(data)
    cdef uintptr_t ptr = <uintptr_t>(get_message(typ))
    return <const void*>(ptr)
```

```
def get_message(typ):
    if typ == 1:
        req_msg.type = 12
        req_msg.subtype = 2
        req_msg.action = 3
        req_msg.checksum = 0x1234
        return addressof(req_msg)
    else:
        return "String object From Python"
```

```
$ ./main
Printing in C - String object From Python
Printing in C - 12, 2, 3, 4660
```